# Comparasion between the lists in python

Tags: python

How to retrieve the name of url if the size on disk (of the downloaded file) differs from the size on server (for the url)?

```
import os, glob, urllib

urls_file = open ('urls.txt','r')
urls = urls_file.read().splitlines()
urls_file.close()

for u in urls:
    data = urllib.urlopen(u)
    size_server = data.info()['Content-Length']   

files_disk = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for f in files_disk:
    size_disk = os.stat(f).st_size
```

After that, I did not know how to go ahead, please help.

Comment: The first step to solving a problem is identifying the problem.

Comment: Do the names of your jpg files match the url in some way?

Comment: @zhangxaochen yes. os.path.basename(url) is equal to os.path.basename(file)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

So I am assuming here you are fetching images, and if the `Content-Length` header does not match the file size on disk, you want to get a list of those URLs.

Try this:

```
url_size = {}

with open('urls.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      url = line.strip()
      if len(url):
          try:
              data = urllib.urlopen(url)
              url_size[os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)] = data.info()['Content-Length']
          except:
              print('Cannot fetch information for: {}'.format(url))


for fname in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    try:
        disk_size = os.stat(fname).st_size
        if url_size.get(fname) != disk_size:
            print('{} does not match fetched size of {}'.format(fname, url_size.get(fname))
    except:
        print('Cannot fetch file size for {}'.format(fname))
```

Don't forget to import the libraries.